# Finding substring in python

Tags: python, string, loops

I'm new to python and I'm trying different methods to accomplish the same task, right now I'm trying to figure out how to get a substring out of a string using a `for loop` and a `while loop`. I quickly found that this is a really easy task to accomplish using `regex`. For example if I have a string: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP" and I want to find if "CDE" exists then print out "CDE" + the rest of the string how would I do that using loops? Right now I'm using:

```
for i, c in enumerate(myString):
```

which returns each index and character, which I feel is a start but I can't figure out what to do after. I also know there are a lot of build in functions to find substrings by doing: myString.(Function) but I would still like to know if it's possible doing this with loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Given:

```
s = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
targets = 'CDE','XYZ','JKL'
```

#### With loops:

```
for t in targets:
    for i in range(len(s) - len(t) + 1):
        for j in range(len(t)):
            if s[i + j] != t[j]:
                break
        else:
            print(s[i:])
            break
    else:
        print(t,'does not exist')
```

#### Pythonic way:

```
for t in targets:
    i = s.find(t)
    if i != -1:
        print(s[i:])
    else:
        print(t,'does not exist')
```

#### Output (in both cases):

```
CDEFGHIJKLMNOP
XYZ does not exist
JKLMNOP
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a concise way to do so:

```
s = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"
if "CDE" in s: 
    print s[s.find("CDE")+len("CDE"):]
else: 
    print s
```

Prints:

```
FGHIJKLMNOP
```

The caveat here is of course, **if the sub-string is not found, the original string will be returned.**

Why do this? Doing so allows you to check whether or not the original string was found or not. As such, this can be conceptualized into a simple function (warning: no type checks enforced for brevity - it is left up to the reader to implement them as necessary):

```
def remainder(string, substring):
    if substring in string:
        return string[string.find(substring)+len(substring):]
    else:
        return string
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the remainder of the string using a for-loop:

```
n = len(substr)
rest = next((s[i+n:] for i in range(len(s) - n + 1) if s[i:i+n] == substr),
            None) # return None if substr not in s
```

It is equivalent to:

```
_, sep, rest = s.partition(substr)
if substr and not sep: # substr not in s
   rest = None
```